# App doesn't post when input is "1 or 1=1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this express server and whenever you post username or password `1 or 1=1` it will not respond. there will be no console output or errors. And it will keep working after that.

I have tried adding `app.post("*")` at the top of the code and it won't even fire the event (so its not sql or the app.use).

If you want to test it go to https://speedcubing.top/login

index.js

```js
const cubing = require('./cubing.js')
const mysql = require('./SQL.js')
const express = require('express')
const cookies = require('cookie-parser')
const uuid = require('uuid')

const app = express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookies())
app.use(express.static('static'))

//database
const sql = new mysql('localhost', 'user', 'pass')
const systemdb = sql.database('speedcubingsystem')

//use
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  cubing.info("use")
  let redir = false
  if (req.url.endsWith('/') && req.url != '/') {
    redir = true
    req.url = req.url.slice(0, -1)
  }
  if (req.subdomains[0] == 'www') {
    redir = true
  }
  if (req.url.includes('?')) {
    redir = true
    req.url = req.url.split('?')[0]
  }
  if (redir) 
    res.redirect('https://speedcubing.top' + req.url)
  else {
    if (req.url != 'myip') {
      req.loginName = ''
      req.admin = false
      if (req.cookies.login !== undefined) {
        const result = await systemdb.query("SELECT user,admin FROM web_user WHERE token='" + req.cookies.login.token + "'")
        if (result.length > 0) {
          req.loginName = result[0].user
          req.admin = result[0].admin.lastIndexOf(1) !== -1
        }
      }
    }
    next()
  }
})
//index page
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', {
    loginName: req.loginName,
  })
})
//login page
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  cubing.info("post login")
  const name = mysql.validateString(req.body.username)
  const pw = mysql.validateString(req.body.password)
  if ((await systemdb.query('SELECT * FROM web_user WHERE user=' + name + ' AND password=' + pw)).length > 0) {
    const token = uuid.v4()
    systemdb.query("UPDATE web_user SET token='" + token + "' WHERE user=" + name + ' AND password=' + pw)
    res.cookie('login', { token: token }, { httpOnly: false })
    res.redirect('/')
  } else res.render('login.ejs', {
      loginName: req.loginName,
      error: true,
    })
})
app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  cubing.info("get login")
  if (req.loginName != '') 
    res.redirect('https://speedcubing.top')
  else res.render('login.ejs', {
    loginName: '',
    error: false
  })
})
//logout
app.get('/logout', async (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('login')
  res.redirect('/')
})

app.listen(25080, function () {
  cubing.info('Listening on /0.0.0.0:25080')
})
```

login.ejs

```html
<title>speedcubing.top</title>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/a.css">
</head>
<body><div class="wrapper">
  <%- include("./global/header.ejs") %>
  <table width="200" border="0" align="center">
    <tr><td>
      <form action="login" method="post">
        <% if(error !== undefined && error){%>
          <p><%= "invalid usr/pw" %></p>
        <% } %>
        username: <input type="text" name="username" ><br/>
        password: <input type="password" name="password" ><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
      </form>
    </td></tr>   
  </table>
</div>
<%- include("./global/footer.ejs") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on what `mysql.validateString` really does, I'd say: Welcome to the world of [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @derpirscher it adds '' and replaces ' for \' and its not sql injection since i know this in vulnerable and i tired but it didn't respond with sql injection and i added a post that doesn't even call sql and it still doesn't respond

Comment: I would one thing to what @derpirscher said, you need validate the email and passwords before using the `validateString`  check if Email using regex and check if password one the same method

Comment: I'll try @Ibrahimshamma but it wasn't firing the `app.post("*", (req,res) => console.log(req.body)` and i put it just after `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))` (when testing)

Comment: Probably something in your post-handler is throwing an exception. And as you don't have  any visible error handling, you have nothing that returns some status code in case of an exception

Comment: add a `console.log('SELECT * FROM web_user WHERE user=' + name + ' AND password=' + pw)` before you execute your query and see if the query is valid.

Comment: there is no console output even though I cubing.log (console.log with timestamp) at the start of the post

Comment: @derpirscher if you read the comments above its not even firing the post request

Comment: Then try adding some error handling to your `app.use(...)` handler. Maybe this is throwing an error

Comment: i have logs for when the use is called and when i put `1 or 1=1` it does not say that use is being fired nor is the app.post and when i use other login it will say use is fireed and post is.

Comment: Do you have any other middlewares included? Because something is hanging or throwing an error in that very special case. Try adding something like `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log("req start"); next() }` as the very first handler, ie directly after `const app = express()`; So, when you get that output, you at least know the request is being dealt with at the server

Comment: One issue is, that because of something like `app.use(async (req, res, next) => {...})` the default error handling of express doesn't catch any exception thrown within `{...}` because, well, it's async ... And if there is something thrown, there won't be any call to `next()` or `res.end()` anymore and the client keeps waiting until the timeout occurs.

Comment: Furhtermore, can you reproduce this issue on your local machine? If not, this might not even be a problem of your code but at some proxy (or whatever) in between. Although I couldn't imagine what that problem might be ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249533/discussion-between-hi12167pies-and-derpirscher).